# adding table data to form new column- how can i add data from custom table to obtain new data column on the same custom table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure; the procedure will have a date range as its parameters and a declared table as such:

```
create proc cumulative(@startdate smalldatetime, @enddate smalldatetime)
as
begin
declare @mc int, @dc int
declare @table table(pkey INT IDENTITY(1,1) not null, public int, private int, Month_Year nvarchar(255),
publiccumulative int, privatecumulative int)

insert into @table
select
sum(case when a.p_cif = cif_number then 1 else 0 end) public,
sum(case when a.p_cif <> cif_number then 1 else 0 end) private,
Month_Year,0,0
```

I set the value of @mc and @dc and use the update statement like this:

```
set @mc = (select count(parent_cif) 
 from public a inner join private b on a.group_id = b.group_id where 
p_cif = cif_number and startdate < @fromdate ) 

update @table
set publiccumulative = @mc + public

set @dc = (select count(p_cif) 
 from public a inner join private b on a.group_id = b.group_id where 
p_cif <> cif_number and startdate < @fromdate )

update @table
set privatecumulative = @mc + private
```

I would like the column of public cumulative to add the value of @mc(value of mc is 379) to the value of public, and the column of private cumulative to add the value of @dc(value of dc is 223) to the value of private for each of the months to get results like this:

```
pkey public private month_year publiccumulative privatecumulative 
1      36      27    Feb-2022       436                264
2      21      14    Jan-2022       400                237
3      160     115   Mar-2022       596                379
```

while this is correct for the month of January, when I get the value of @mc, the value of public cumulative column adds the public value to only that value of @mc instead of the corresponding value of public for each of the following months and same goes for the value of the private cumulative column so I end up with a result like this:

```
pkey public private month_year publiccumulative privatecumulative 
1      36      27    Feb-2022       415                250
2      21      14    Jan-2022       400                237
3      160     115   Mar-2022       539                338
```

How do I make it add to the corresponding columns for each month after the month of January?

Comment: please show your attempt and explain where you are stuck

Comment: Please do not post as image, use text instead. Your previous before editing is good

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `SUM() OVER ()` to get the cumulative sum.

Hopefully you have date or datetime column in your table if not you need to convert it to date for the `ORDER BY`

```
UPDATE T
SET    publiccumulative = @mc + T.cum_sum
FROM   (
           SELECT *, cum_sum = SUM(public) OVER (ORDER BY d.thedate)
           FROM   yourtable t
                  CROSS APPLY
                  (
                      SELECT thedate = convert(date, '01-' + month_year, 106) 
                  ) d
       ) T
```